# Taylor and geometric series

Tags: calculus, sequences-and-series

1) iF $f(x) = x^2 +x$, find the taylor series for f centered at a = 2.

2)what is the sum from 1 to infinity of $(.95)^n$

I got these questions wrong on my last test, and I'm not really sure how to go about solving it.

Comment: Could you tell us what your answers were on your last test, or did you leave the questions completely blank?  It will help us give you more relevant answers if we know what you did wrong previously.

Answer (score 1):

1. The [Taylor series](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Taylor_series) of an infinitely differentiable function at a point is a representation of a function given by an infinite sum of terms of a specific form. Let $f(x)$ be the function and $a$ be the point, then the Taylor series is given by $$f(a) + \frac{f'(a)}{1!}(x-a) + \frac{f''(a)}{2!}(x-a)^2 + \cdots + \frac{f^{(n)}(a)}{n!}(x-a)^n + \cdots $$ where $f^{(n)}$ is the $n$-th derivative of the function.

In your case, we have $$f(x) = 6 + \frac{5}{1!}(x-2) + \frac{2}{2!}(x-2)^2 + \frac{0}{3!}(x-2)^3.$$ The last term given above is zero as we have a zero in the numerator. All subsequent terms are  zero as $f^{(n)}=0$ for $n\geq 3$.

For Two. I suppose that you want to find $$\sum_{n=1}^\infty (0.95)^n = 0.95 + 0.95^2 + 0.95^3 + \cdots $$

As this is a [geometric series](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Geometric_series) with $a=0.95$ and $r=0.95$ we have the sum given by $$\frac{a}{1-r} = \frac{0.95}{1-0.95}=19$$